# Alternatives to boost::hash_combine that have associative property?

Tags: c++, boost, hashcode

I am looking for a `hash_combine` function that has the associative property.

For example, I'd like to be able to either combine the values a, b, c, d one after another to get the hash key for the sequence, or combine a and b, then c and d, and combine the results. The two methods should give the same result.

`boost::hash_combine` does not have that property:

```
  // a * b * c * d                                                                                                                                                                                        
  std::size_t seed = 0;
  boost::hash_combine(seed, 234);
  boost::hash_combine(seed, 62);
  boost::hash_combine(seed, 675);
  boost::hash_combine(seed, 916);
  std::cout << seed << std::endl; // 706245846748881

  // (a * b) * (c * d)                                                                                                                                                                                    
  std::size_t seed1 = 0;
  boost::hash_combine(seed1, 234);
  boost::hash_combine(seed1, 62);
  std::size_t seed2 = 0;
  boost::hash_combine(seed2, 675);
  boost::hash_combine(seed2, 916);
  boost::hash_combine(seed1, seed2); // 11337801211148
```

Is there any good `hash_combine` function that has it?

P.S.: The reason for doing this is that I assign hash keys to sequences that I find in a DAG. I'm running dynamic programming to find the hash keys for (the sequences between) all pairs of states.

Answer (score 1):

How about plain xor?

```
std::size_t seed = 0;
seed ^= boost::hash_value(234);
seed ^= boost::hash_value(62);
...
```

Comment: Thanks, that would work. Does anyone know about the behavior of this versus `hash_combine`, in terms of likely collisions etc.?

Comment: The [reference documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_combine) has the exact formula used by `boost::hash_combine`.

Comment: One immediate problem you can see with xor is that A ^ A == 0 for any A. So [a, a], [b, b], [c, c]... will all have the same hash. Also, [a, b, c, a] has the same hash as [b, c]. `+` would do better than `^` for these cases.

Comment: Hmm tricky, I'll probably not want to use it then ... Regarding the reference for `boost::hash_combine`, it says `seed ^= hash_value(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);`

Comment: This introduces the Commutative property as-well, which can be less then ideal as it would produce the same hash for any collections that share the same elements in the same quantity, it would also be cancelative on repeats.